# Can the top and bottom having the same pattern be called "outfit"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image] ([Source](https://nkf.vn/nkbd2202005-bo-ke-co-sen#lg=1&slide=1))

Women in hot countries often wears these clothes at home. The top and the bottom share the same pattern.

**Do you say "she is wearing an outfit"?**

[image] ([source](https://www.lazada.vn/tag/set-ao-kieu-quan-dui-nam/))

Or the above guy wears a T shirt and a pair of shorts which share the same pattern.

**Is he wearing an outfit?**

The dictionary says "[outfit](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/outfit_1?q=outfit): a set of clothes that you wear together, especially for a particular occasion or purpose"

What if I created my own top-bottom combination that looks weird. For example, I wear a shirt with a tie and jean shorts. Do this set of clothes called "the outfit"?

Comment: An outfit is a set of clothes, often worn for a specific purpose or event, often designed to be worn together.  The patterns might match, or they might not.  It's quite a general word, and could mean almost any combination of clothing.  It's best to look up words in a good dictionary if you are unsure of their meaning.

Comment: S/he is wearing a _matching_ outfit. We wouldn't refer to 'an outfit' without describing it in some way.

Comment: Please edit to show that you've looked up the meaning of the word "outfit," and then explain why you suspect it might *not* apply in these cases. Voting to close for not meeting the basic on-topic requirements for questions about word usage. I would think you'd be familiar with them, but please [read the help pages](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) if you haven't yet.

Comment: I'd say that common phrases for the outfit in the picture are 'co-ord set' and 'two-piece set' - that is, an outfit made from matching colours, prints, or fabrics. Whether it's a matching top and skirt outfit or a coordinating jogger and sweatshirt ensemble, co-ords are separates that are designed to be worn together.

Comment: Co-ord sets have become very fashionable in recent years, but I recall that my mother had a 'twinset' 60 years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The word **outfit** in American English is most frequently used of an *ensemble* of clothing, something for the torso, something for the lower half of the body, and it can even include a hat.  It refers to how the individual elements look in combination.  Most often it is used of women's clothing but not always, and the top and bottom matching does not disqualify the ensemble from being called an outfit.

> She was wearing a summer outfit --  a short-sleeved blouse,  pedal-pushers, and a straw sun hat.
>
> She was wearing a chic outfit that looked rather  like a uniform: a gingham blouse with matching skirt and matching gingham pillbox hat.
>
> This guy came into the luncheonette wearing a strange outfit --military camouflage trousers, combat boots, a white dress shirt with a button-down collar and paisley tie, and a bright yellow hard-hat like you would see at a construction site. He was carrying an armful of blueprints and didn't know where to set them down.

Comment: What if I created my own top-bottom combination that looks weird. For example, I wear a shirt with a tie and jean shorts. Do this set of clothes called "**an outfit**"?

Comment: @Tom Yes. It basically just refers to the totality of the look, clothing-wise. Pretty much any articles of clothing worn at the same time could be described as an outfit. Usually the articles of an outfit are intended to go together or fit some common pattern, but you could have a strange, weird or mismatched outfit consisting of random articles of clothing. If you came into work as you described, someone might ask if you picked your outfit in the dark.

Comment: One could use the word in good-natured mockery:  *That's quite an outfit you've got on there, Tom.*

Answer (score 0):

Collins Dictionary defines *outfit*:

> An outfit is a set of clothes.

M+W says in its noun2b

> a clothing ensemble often for a *special* occasion or activity

Cambridge Dictionary says

> a set of clothes worn for a *particular* occasion or activity

Though the latter two dictionaries mention *special* and *particular*, none say that the top and the bottom cannot share the same pattern.  Hence, we should be able to use this noun here.